# Multi Column Cardinal / Groupby?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic I'm trying to count combination of fields values.

In SQL this would be like

SELECT a, b, COUNT(a) FROM tbl GROUP BY a, b

(My data is Apache logs, and I'm counting combinations of 
client_ip+method+response_code)

Example data

a, b, c, d

a, b, c, d

a, b, c, e

Expected Output

a, b, c, d = 2

a, b, c, e = 1

Fields are all text
Matches should be exact, not fuzzy
Output needs to show the combination and the count
I don't want to enable fielddata on text fields as my code will be opensource so I want minimal changes to out-the-box elastic to mimic users

Spent hours reading and am non the wiser, every example is very different to this.

Any help appreciated!

I've been looking at:

Cardinal, multiple cardinal
Aggs, Group, Fields vs Keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the three ways *(primarily two, although I've mentioned three, first two are similar)* to achieve this:

### Solution 1: Using Elasticsearch DSL

I've mentioned a sample mapping, sample documents, sample aggregation query and response:

**Mapping:**

Note that I've created all the fields in [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) format. Which means for every field of type `text` for e.g. `client_ip`, you have its sibling field `client_ip.keyword` which would be of type `keyword`. It is on this field below aggregation query would work.

You cannot run aggregation queries on [Text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) type unless you have `fielddata` set as `enabled`. I wouldn't recommend this instead, iff you *have to* do this, the best make use of multi-fields as mentioned below.

```
PUT myipindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties":{
        "client_ip": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "method": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "response_code":{
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Documents:**

```
POST myipindex/mydocs/1
{
  "client_ip": "10.10.10.10",
  "method": "GET",
  "response_code": "200"
}

POST myipindex/mydocs/2
{
  "client_ip": "10.10.10.10",
  "method": "GET",
  "response_code": "200"
}

POST myipindex/mydocs/3
{
  "client_ip": "10.10.10.11",
  "method": "GET",
  "response_code": "200"
}

POST myipindex/mydocs/4
{
  "client_ip": "10.10.10.11",
  "method": "POST",
  "response_code": "200"
}
```

**Aggregation Query:**

I've simply created 3 [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) in the below tree/sub-aggregation form to help you understand:

```
Terms Aggregation for client_ip
- Terms Aggregation for method
 - Terms Aggregation for response_code
```

Below is the actual query:

```
POST myipindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "my_ip":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "client_ip.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_method": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "method.keyword",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "my_response_code": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "response_code.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "min_doc_count": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Aggregation Response:**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_ip" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "10.10.10.10",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "my_method" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "GET",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "my_response_code" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "200",
                      "doc_count" : 2
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "10.10.10.11",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "my_method" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "GET",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "my_response_code" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "200",
                      "doc_count" : 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : "POST",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "my_response_code" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "200",
                      "doc_count" : 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Solution 2: Using Elasticsearch DSL with painless script

This solution is similar to the solution 1, where I'm still making use of Terms Aggregation but I've written a custom script in order to do this.

Thought you might want to prefer this over the solution 1, due to the output format.

**Aggregation Query:**

```
POST myipindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myagg": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            return doc['client_ip.keyword'].value + ", " + doc ['method.keyword'].value + ", " + doc['response_code.keyword'].value;
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Aggregation Response:**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "myagg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "10.10.10.10, GET, 200",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "10.10.10.11, GET, 200",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "10.10.10.11, POST, 200",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Solution 3: Using SQL Access if you have Elasticsearch xpack

If you have access to xpack's [SQL Access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html) feature, then you can simply execute the below query:

```
POST /_xpack/sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "SELECT client_ip, method, response_code, count(*) FROM myipindex GROUP BY client_ip, method, response_code"

}
```

**Response:**

```
   client_ip   |    method     | response_code |   COUNT(1)    
---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------
10.10.10.10    |GET            |200            |2              
10.10.10.11    |GET            |200            |1              
10.10.10.11    |POST           |200            |1
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks Kamal,
I still get:

"reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [client_ip] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

Is enabling fielddata necessary?  I'm trying to keep as vanilla Elastic config as possible

Comment: That's because you cannot run the queries I've mentioned on `text` type. You would need to have these fields as `keyword`. The reason is the fields of type `text` goes through analysis phase. For e.g. if you field "description": "my name is joe", then Elasticsearch would break down these sentence into tokens, and thereby save them in inverted index. That's why elasticsearch has two types for string values. Keyword for exact match and Text for typical search/token based use case. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Comment: Where do I set 'keyword' rather than 'field' ?  I tried in search syntax but no luck.  I can't see anywhere in Kibana.  And I can't see anywhere in logstash?

Comment: @AndyShepherd, you would need to delete the index, recreate the index with the mappings I've mentioned, reingest the documents and run the aggregation queries. I'd suggest create a dummy index with the above mapping and run the queries to see how result would appear. This would give you an idea before you do it on your actual index on which you'd want to make the changes.